# Why are lower tomato leaves like these?

Tags: leaves, tomatoes

I have a cherry tomato plant that is staked and caged. It is in an outdoor covered patio in South Florida.  It is about 5ft. tall and is producing several fruit. I currently use miracle-gro 24-8-16 biweekly. (I am about to switch to the 18-18-21 since most of my plants have begun to flower.

The fruit and the leaves on the top look great. However some of the bottom leaves have the pattern pictured below. I've been looking everywhere to see what this could be but to no success. I am not overly concerned since the plant is growing fine and is producing fruit.

Anybody happen to know what the cause of this is as well as treatment, if necessary?

[image]

[image]

Comment: my guesses would be either sunburn, or letting the leaves stay wet...

Answer (score 1):

[image: leaf hopper damage]

There are some serpiginous lesions on the leaves which argues against it being solar damage, and more likely to be insect damage such as a leafhopper as per the image above.

Comment: Here in Ohio, I have had stinkbugs leave this kind of damage.